# read_csv, use delimeter in part of the data

Tags: pandas, csv, merge

I have a csv file which contain data of the form (YY,MM,DD,hh.mm,ss), followed by a measurement. the problem is that all are separated with a ','. When i use

```
pd.read_csv(path_new_data, sep=',')
```

i get all columns separated like below.

```
    18  1   8   15  17  5   97.216
0   18  1   8   15  22  7   98.039
1   18  1   8   15  27  8   97.587
2   18  1   8   15  32  9   97.535
3   18  1   8   15  37  11  97.637
```

What i want is to get the first 6 columns merged into onto one or even better to specify the delimiter ony on the last columns and get something like the following

```
    181815175   97.216
0   181815227   98.039
1   181815278   97.587
2   181815329   97.535
3   1818153711  97.637
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not necessary, only define columns names and use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys can be common abbreviations like ['year', 'month', 'day', 'minute', 'second', 'ms', 'us', 'ns']) or plurals of the same.

```
temp=u"""18,1,8,15,17,5,97.216
18,1,8,15,22,7,98.039
18,1,8,15,27,8,97.587
18,1,8,15,32,9,97.535
18,1,8,15,37,11,97.637"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
names = ['year','month','day','hour','minute','second','data']
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=names)
print (df)
   year  month  day  hour  minute  second    data
0    18      1    8    15      17       5  97.216
1    18      1    8    15      22       7  98.039
2    18      1    8    15      27       8  97.587
3    18      1    8    15      32       9  97.535
4    18      1    8    15      37      11  97.637

#add 20 for correct parsing
df['year'] = '20' + df['year'].astype(str)
cols = ['year','month','day','hour','minute','second']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[cols])
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
     data                date
0  97.216 2018-01-08 15:17:05
1  98.039 2018-01-08 15:22:07
2  97.587 2018-01-08 15:27:08
3  97.535 2018-01-08 15:32:09
4  97.637 2018-01-08 15:37:11
```

Comment: thanks, that works nicely! Just  for future use do you know if I can apply delimiter in part of the data through read_csv() or I have to process each line individually?

Comment: @saias - Unfortunately is is problem,  close is use [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html?highlight=read_fwf#files-with-fixed-width-columns) and then replace whitespaces by empty strings.